# How to Change the content of the dropdown list box when value is selected in dropdown list 1

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown list once is about the area another one is the name.In first dropdown list i have set a cookie to get the area which is originally  get from sql database.Now the second dropdown list is to get the username.Therefore once the area is change, the second dropdown will get different name according to the first dropdown list .The area cookie is L,P,W ,how do i manage to change the different area to get different name ?

```html
<form id="form" >
   <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="1" border="0" >
 <tr>
     <td>  Sales Area 
  <select >
        <?php
         
        $sarea = explode(",",$_COOKIE['cooAreaCode']);
        foreach($sarea as $item){
        ?>
        <option  id="slct" value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
  
        <?php
  
        }
       
   $sql = "SELECT  StaffName FROM tblStaff WHERE AreaCode= '$item'";
      $rs = odbc_exec($link,$sql);
  while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
   $porr[] = $row;
    }
    
   odbc_free_result($rs);   
  odbc_close($link); 


 
        ?>
       
       </select>
       </td>
     <td>  Staff Name 
  <select name="sales_staff_s">
        <?php
         for($i=0; $i < count($porr);$i++) {
        $staff = explode(",",$porr[$i]['StaffName'] );
        foreach($staff as $itm){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo strtolower($itm); ?>"><?php echo $itm; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
  }
        ?>
       
       </select>
       </td>
     
  
 </tr>
 </form>
```

Comment: You need to bind change event on your dropdown & based upon selection

Comment: Any suggestion to bind change event,because i not really good in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add onchange event to your first dropdown list:

```
<td>
    <select name="sales_area" id="sales_area" onchange="getSalesName();">
        <?php
        $sarea = explode(",",$_COOKIE['cooAreaCode']);
        foreach($sarea as $item){ ?>
            <option id="slct" value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <div id="sales_area_options">
    </div>
</td>
```

2) You need to use ajax to populate the options for your second dropdown list by passing the selected option from your first dropdown list. The JavaScript function:

```
function getSalesName() {
    var sales_area = document.getElementById("sales_area").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: website_url + "/ajax/get_sales_name.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'sales_area': sales_area},
        success: function(data) {
            var opts = '<select name="sales_staff_s">';
            $(data).each(function(index, val) {
                opts += '<option value="'+val.id+'">'+val.name+'</option>';
            });
            opts += '</select>';            
            $("#sales_area_options").html(opts);    
        }
    });
}
```

3) Your SQL queries and exploding the values for the second dropdown list should be in the new PHP file:

```
$item = $_POST['sales_area'];
$sql = "SELECT  StaffName FROM tblStaff WHERE AreaCode= '$item'";
...
```